# Matlab - Compile Program w\ Separate Functions

Tags: matlab

I wrote a GUI program which makes use of separate m-functions. What I have done thus far was to add the paths of the folders where the sub-functions are stored on startup, and remove those paths on close.

Everything works fine, but when I tried to compile the project, I got an error message (attached) which suggests that ADDPATH is not a function that can be used in a standalone app.

Is there a way to overcome with w\o any major changes in the program? Maybe some way to include those functions w\o ADDPATH?

[image: Error message]

Comment: Putting all the functions in the same folder eliminates the use for `addpath` at least

Comment: It does, but it doesn't make for a 'clean' project :)